# Minimum angular version for using angular material

Tags: angular, angular-material

I am currently using Angular 2 and wish to use Angular Material but it has some dependency issues. Is there a way to solve those. Or if I migrate to a newer  angular version, which **minimum angular version** should I migrate to so that i can use angular material. Any other alternative not mentioned in the question is also welcome.

Comment: Are you actually using version 2 of the Angular library, or are you stating that you're using the newer Angular?

Answer (score 0):

When you use a current angular-cli version you can just type `ng add @angular/material`

I prefer to use the latest stable version of angular cli which is currently 7.1.4

Here some Information about angular-cli: https://github.com/angular/angular-cli

Answer (score 0):

The minimum version of Angular Material is **5.2.5**.

Using the Angular CLI *ng add command* will update your Angular project with the correct dependencies, perform configuration changes and execute initialization code.

```
ng add @angular/material
```

Comment: I am asking about minimum angular version which i should be using so that I can use angular material..

Comment: https://material.angular.io/ ? Look upper right. you can select the version that is currently supported. and as praveen says. 5.2.5